# Easy way to make a numeric vector ordinal in R?

Tags: r

I have a simple question. I have a vector of years, spanning 1945:2000, with many repeated years. I want to make this an ordinal vector, so that 1945 is changed to 1, 1946 to 2, etc...

Obviously in this case the easiest way is just to subtract 1944 from the vector. But I have to do this with other numberic vectors that are not evenly spaced.

Is there an R function that does this?

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
as.numeric(factor(x))
```

For example:

```
x <- sample(1945:2010, 40)
ordinal_x <- as.numeric(as.factor(x))

plot(x, ordinal_x)
```

[image]

Notice that `ordinal_x` skips the gaps in `x`.

Comment: @RHertel According to the OP this looks like the desired behavior: `Obviously in this case the easiest way is just to subtract 1944 from the vector. But I have to do this with other numberic vectors that are not evenly spaced.` If the OP had wanted skipped years to lead to gaps, subtracting 1944 from the vector would always work.

Comment: Fair enough ;-) Thanks for the answer, I think you're right.